# I have different classes and I want to make a vector with objects from those classes and sort it by a value

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, multiple-inheritance

I have the first class.

```
class Class1
{

public:
   Class1();
   double getVal();
   bool operator<(Class1& A) { return getVal() > A.getVal(); }
virtual ~Class1();
}
```

And from this class I derive two classes.

```
class Class2 : virtual public Class1
{
 protected:
   int val1;
 public:
 int getVal(){ return val; }
 bool operator<(Class1& A) { return getVal() > A.getVal(); }
 }
```

And the second class.

```
 class Class3 : virtual public Class1
 {
    protected:
       double val2;
    public:
       double getVal(){ return val; }
       bool operator<(Class1& A) { return getVal() > A.getVal(); }
 }
```

And finally from these classes I derive one class.

```
 class Class4 : public Class2, public Class3
 {
   protected:
       char* info;
   public:
       double getVal(){ return val1+val2; }
       bool operator<(Class1& A) { return getVal() > A.getVal(); }
 }
```

And in main I have:

```
 void main(){
     vector<Class1*> vec;
     vec.push_back(new Class2(3));
     vec.push_back(new Class3(5));
     vec.push_back(new Class4(2));
    sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
 }
```

The code is pushing back objects in the vector just fine, but when I'm trying to sort it nothing happens. 
I suspect that is something wrong with the parent class (Class1) and mainly the getVal() method, but I don't know what to do.
The question is: How can I sort this vector?

Comment: *but when I'm trying to sort it nothing happens* -- Things *are* happening.  The `std::sort` is doing exactly what you wrote, which is to sort the pointer values.

Comment: Your methods could be `const` (and take const references).

Comment: Is it intended to hide `getVal()` in derived classes ? using other names seems better. (or if you want virtual getter, they should return same type (`int` and `double` are not co-variant)).

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that you have a vector of *pointers*. Therefore the comparison done by `std::sort` is done using the *pointers* and not the structures pointed to by them.

For it to work, you have to either provide a global `operator<` function which takes two pointers as arguments. Or you provide a comparison function as a third argument to [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). Both needs to dereference the pointers.

Also, you still need to mark your functions as `virtual` for polymorphism to work.